# cannot resize table to fit div content

Tags: html, css

I hope you can help, problem is that I have a table which I cannot set its maximum width and it is overlapping the div. I tried to change its div in CSS but in vain.

the repairs table is the div for the table, I also trief to contain it within another div named tableholder but in vain again.

```
.repairstable {
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;        
     table-layout:fixed;
     overflow:hidden;
     max-height:125px;
     max-width:75px;
}
#tableholder {
    width 300px;
}
```

Comment: What's the css for the table, also some markup would be nice too.

Comment: JSFiddle almost guarantees a response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables always expand to a minimum width to get all cells in each row displaying correctly. If you restrict a table to 300px and you have two cells each containing some really long word (say 160px) the table will be 320px wide.

So you have to make sure that the table content fits into your maximum width.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information that helped me fixed this issue along with using Reset CSS